# Reading LAZ file in Python directly?

Tags: python, las

I am able to read .las file in Python using laspy in Windows as below:

```
las_filename = 'abc.las'
inFile = laspy.file.File(las_filename, mode='r')
```

But when I put a .laz file in this code, I get the below error:

> LaspyException: Error mapping file: Laszip was not found on the system

How to directly read a .laz file as I do with .las file or if there is a way in Python to convert .laz to .las and then read it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500149/laspy-cannot-find-laszip-when-is-installed-from-source-laszip-is-in-path

Comment: @bugmenot123 how to do it for Windows?

Comment: I added instructions as an answer. Please update your question to specify Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not very helpful unfortunately.

You are missing the required library LASzip on your system as well as the laszip.exe tool.

For Windows you can get the LASzip DLL file from the archive the LAStools project provides at https://lastools.github.io/download/LAStools.zip

You can find it in `LAStools/LASzip/dll/` in said archive.

For quick and dirty solution you should be able to simply place the appropriate LASzip DLL (probably LASzip64.dll) into the same directory as your Python script. If that does not work or for a proper installation, check the sister site https://superuser.com/ or other sources for how to install libraries on Windows.

Do the same for the `laszip.exe` and/or `laszip64.exe` from `LAStools/bin/`.

Then it should not give this error anymore.

Comment: So, I don't need to change anything just .laz file insted of .las file as in above code?

Comment: If yes, then your answer doesn't works. It gives me the same error after putting the required dll file in the folder where the script resides.

Comment: Did you launch the Python interpreter in the same directory that your script and the DLL(s) is in?

Comment: Yes, I did the same.

Comment: Sorry,I missed something. Updated the answer, please try again.

Comment: Working. Thanks. It was the laszip.exe file which was missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pylas 

las = pylas.read('D:/Research/LiDAR/LAZ_2/20150403_319050.laz')    
las = pylas.convert(las)    
las.write('D:/Research/LiDAR/LAZ_2/20150403_319050.las')
```

Comment: How does this code relate to the  `Laszip was not found on the system` issue?  Please edit the answer to provide more information

Comment: I think that this solution is a great one and a simple workaround. pylas depends on lazrs, which can be installed through "pip" and does not depends on laszip. I've just tested the code in Google Colab and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Guadancil11 Thanks for your comment and for identifying the library that I needed to install. This was the exact information I needed to fix a script I had written for batch filtering of vegetation.