# Converting LAZ to LAS using laspy

Tags: python, lidar, las, laspy, laz

I would like to convert .laz file to .las. I am using Python and I have installed laspy with lazrs extension.

I tried in Pyscripter (v4.0) following solution (this solution was mentioned here: [Reading LAZ file in Python directly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332366/reading-laz-file-in-python-directly)):

```
import laspy
las = pylas.read('D:\\TEST\\test.laz')    
las = pylas.convert(las)    
las.write('D:\\TEST\\test.las')
```

And it even doesn't read the file. It says: "

> thread '' panicked at 'index 17529 out of range for slice of
> length 17521', src\libcore\slice\mod.rs:2725:5

"

However, I wanted to download LASzip (https://laszip.org/), but there is no win installation file available. It seems the site doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to convert laz to las?

Comment: lastools (https://laszip.org/) does not use windows executable. Just extract the files to a folder and run it from the command line in this folder.

Comment: there were exe files availabe I assume (since there is a link http://lastools.org/download/laszip.exe at the website https://rapidlasso.com/laszip/ ). Can you give me some more instructions on how to run files from the command line (I know what CL is, just I am not sure which file to run and what are the commands available). Maybe you can post an example of a line.

Comment: The .exe mere gave you the files in a package, much like a zip. It does not run a GUI program. It is exceptionally simple. Here are many examples
 
https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/laszip_README.txt

laszip lidar.las turn lidar.las into lidar.zip and this would do all files in a folder laszip *.las
 
The Readme in the zip or .exe has all the info

Comment: This works for me:  https://github.com/LummiGIS/LAS_tools/blob/main/LAZ_to_LAS.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a python fix, but in ArcPro you can just use the Convert LAS tool. I find even though its an optional parameter, you just need to make sure the coordinate system is set and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that worked with python. Thanks to GBG's comment.

"This works for me: github.com/LummiGIS/LAS_tools/blob/main/LAZ_to_LAS.py"